# Javascript random array checker error

Tags: javascript, arrays

Working on a game and cant figure out why my functions aren't working right..

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

By my knowledge one of my functions have a infinite loop(?)

I have a array witch needs to have 3 random speeds in it.

```
var randomSpeeds = new Array();
```

I have a function made witch generate a random speed:

```
function generateSpeed() {
    var randomSpeed = Math.random().toFixed(1) * 5;
    if(randomSpeed == 0){
        randomSpeed = 1;
    }
    return randomSpeed;
}
```

The array is filled by this function:

```
function fillSpeedArray() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var randomSpeed = generateSpeed();
        if(speedArrayChecker(randomSpeed) != false) {
            randomSpeeds.splice(i, 0, randomSpeed);
        } else {
            fillSpeedArray();
        }
    }   
}
```

The function loops 3 times and each time it generates a random speed and goos through a if/else statement for checking if the array already has got the random generated number (speedArrayChecker).

The speedArrayChecker:

```
function speedArrayChecker(speed) {
    for(speeds in randomSpeeds) {
        if(speeds != speed) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This last function goos through the array and if the array already go the random generated number, return true else false.

Function called and checked:

```
fillSpeedArray();
console.log(randomSpeeds);
```

By a reason I don't see the functions aren't working correctly.
Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
var randomSpeeds = new Array();
function generateSpeed() {
    var randomSpeed = Math.random().toFixed(1) * 5;
    if(randomSpeed == 0){
        randomSpeed = 1;
    }
    return randomSpeed;
}
function fillSpeedArray() {   
    while (randomSpeeds.length < 3) {
        var randomSpeed = generateSpeed(); 
        if (speedArrayChecker(randomSpeed) != false) {
            randomSpeeds.splice(randomSpeeds.length, 0, randomSpeed);
        }
    }
}
function speedArrayChecker(speed) {
    return randomSpeeds.indexOf(speed) === -1
}
fillSpeedArray();
console.log(randomSpeeds);
```

**Explanation:**

There were two problems with your code.

1. The implementation of the `speedArrayChecker` function was fundamentally flawed. It returned `false` *only* when the `randomSpeeds` was empty.
2. You had an infinite loop caused by infinite recursion.

The solution was to correct the `speedArrayChecker` implementation and to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop(by recursion) here:

```
function fillSpeedArray() {
 for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var randomSpeed = generateSpeed();
        if(speedArrayChecker(randomSpeed) != false) {
            randomSpeeds.splice(i, 0, randomSpeed);
        } else {
            fillSpeedArray();
        }
    }   
}
```

In the `else` if the speed exists already it will call the function it's currently in again and again. This function will never exit, unless you get 3 random speeds perfectly the first time. I would recommend changing `fillSpeedArray()` to maybe `i--`.

On a side note why don't you use `randomSpeeds.push(randomSpeed)` to add speeds to the array.

Comment: Just being pedantic: infinite _recursion_, not infinite loop.

Comment: The first iteration should be a guarantee unique speed and the else will never be hit. The second time if its the same speed, you still need 3 random numbers so step 2 needs to be redone, a for loop will keep iterating each time so you just need to go back down to 0 so the loop will take you back to 1

Comment: You could try two two suggestions I made with your for loop and I don't see any major problems

Comment: use the push method of adding